# Characterising ergodicity of continuous maps

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Hello all.

Suppose $X$ is a Polish space, $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $X$, and $T:X \to X$ is a continuous $\mu$-preserving map which is *not* ergodic.

Does there necessarily exist a Borel set $A \subset X$ such that

- $\mu(A) \in (0,1)$;
- $\mu(A \ \triangle \ T^{-1}(A)) = 0$;
- $A$ has non-empty interior?

What about if we replace the third point with the stronger requirement that $A$ is open?

Many thanks,
Julian.

Comment: Does $T$ preserve the measure?

Comment: Good point! Let's assume it does. (I'll now edit the question accordingly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $T \colon X \to X$ be a minimal transformation of a compact metric space which is not uniquely ergodic, let $\mu$ be a non-ergodic $T$-invariant measure on $X$, and let $A$ be a set with nonempty interior such that $\mu(A \triangle T^{-1}A)=0$. I claim that necessarily $\mu(A)=1$, contradicting the above conjecture. (Some constructions of transformations with the above combination of properties may be found for example in the textbook *Ergodic Theory on Compact Spaces* by Denker, Grillenberger and Sigmund, or in John Oxtoby's classic 1952 article *Ergodic sets*.)

Let $U \subseteq A$ be open and nonempty. Since $T$ is minimal we have $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty T^{-n}U=X$, and indeed even $\bigcup_{n=0}^NT^{-n}U=X$ for some integer $N$ since $X$ is compact. In particular $\bigcup_{n=0}^N T^{-n}A=X$. Let us write
$$\bigcup_{n=0}^N T^{-n}A = A \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^N \left(\left( T^{-n}A\right)\setminus \bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1} T^{-k}A\right)=A \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n,$$
say, which is a disjoint union. We would like to show that this union has measure identical to that of $A$. For each $n$ we have
$$\mu(B_n)=\mu\left(T^{-n}A\setminus \bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1} T^{-k}A\right)\leq \mu\left(T^{-n}A \setminus T^{-(n-1)}A\right)=\mu\left(T^{-1}A \setminus A\right)=0$$ by invariance and the hypothesis $\mu(A \triangle T^{-1}A)=0$. It follows that
$$\mu(A)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^N T^{-n}A \right)=\mu(X)=1$$
so the desired situation can not occur.

Comment: Thank you. This is most helpful. Do you know any conditions on $X$ under which, if $\mu$ is a strictly positive probability measure on $X$, then every minimal $\mu$-preserving continuous transformation is ergodic? (E.g. is this true for Euclidean space $X=\mathbb{R}^n$?)

Comment: @Julian: This is hopeless. On any reasonable space, there will be transformations that are minimal, but not strictly ergodic.

Comment: @Julian: this is equivalent to asking for a condition on $X$ such that every minimal transformation on $X$ is uniquely ergodic, i.e. has only one invariant measure. (If a transformation has two distinct invariant measures then a strict linear combination of the two is never ergodic.) Such conditions do exist: finite spaces $X$ have this property, as does the circle (I think) but as Anthony says this is a severly restrictive requirement. 

The broader stroke of your question seems to be whether ergodicity can be easily characterised using only topological concepts. The answer to this is "No".

Comment: @Ian and Anthony: Just to be clear, I did not say that I require every invariant probability measure of a minimal transformation to be ergodic - I just required that every *strictly positive* invariant probability measure of a minimal transformation had to be ergodic. (By strictly positive, I mean that its support is the whole of $X$). Is this still equivalent to requiring that every minimal transformation is uniquely ergodic? (And in the case $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, if the requirement still is not satisfied, what about if we weaken the requirement by restricting to, say, diffeomorphisms on $X$?)

Comment: @Julian: Every invariant probability measure of a minimal transformation is fully supported, because otherwise its support would be a nonempty closed invariant proper subset, contradicting minimality. So the two statements are equivalent.